# Does iOS support any relative height capability for text views or must height be fixed?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing my first IPhone app and after much struggle and toil I have figured out how to calculate the height of UITextViews as they change with dynamic content and have managed to create a UITableView containing rows with three different UITableCell types and make the heights correct for all my UITextViews and table rows... however, I find this to be incredibly laborious to have to perform these calculations on every text field inside every UITableViewCell contained in my UITableViews. Is it really the case that there is no such thing as a RELATIVE height setting on UILabels or UITextViews?

Having a container expand to fit its contents is defacto in HTML, Android has 'FILL_PARENT" attribute for its containers, does iOS really not have that ability? Do you have to set a FIXED height on every text field?

Answer (score 0):

UITableCell and UITextView both inherit from UIView - take a look at UIView's `autoresizingMask` and `autoresizesSubviews` methods: [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

Comment: Thanks for there reference. However, these attributes mention that a view will autoresize its subviews "When a view’s bounds change".  I am not sure what it means for a view's bounds to change but I assume it means the height or width of a superview changes. The point I am asking about though is how to NOT change the height of any views, but just have the textviews automatically adjust to the content loaded in them. Is that possible?

Comment: For example, in my table view,  at the moment the only way I know how to return the correct number for the TableViewDelegate method 'heightForRowAtIndexPath' is to recalculate the height of each UITextView contained in the UITableViewCell in question, add them up and then add some arbitrary extra amount.  This seems like an excessive amount of code to write. Is there not an easier way?

Comment: Ah, sorry I got you wrong there - should have read your question more thoroughly... Maybe take a look at sizeToFit and sizeThatFits? The UIView Reference mentions that several UIKit elements are using these to return the size that best fits their "internal needs"... I read somewhere that it works for UILabel, however I don't know whether it will work for UITextView, too..

Comment: Well you need SOME code to tell the tableview the height of the cell in question. The tableview will always ask its delegate for this value, so you have to make some connection. Using sizeThatFits for the text content should make this easy, however...

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks so much - I think that sizeToFit and sizeThatFits may indeed help a lot. Is it possible to get a reference to the cell in question for the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method so that I can do something like : return [[cell sizeThatFits] height];

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, just use UITableView's - (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method to get a reference to the cell.